# can't install and use pyaudio in python 3.7

Tags: python, pyaudio

```
C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1>pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qm5dhs1u\\pyaud
io_0fa5615a0f1d45fe897d47e2b712cf51\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qm5dhs1u\\pyaudio_0fa5615a0f1d45fe897d47e2b712cf
51\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"
'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mst52wx_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-head
ers 'c:\python37\Include\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qm5dhs1u\pyaudio_0fa5615a0f1d45fe897d47e2b712cf51\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\
Temp\\pip-install-qm5dhs1u\\pyaudio_0fa5615a0f1d45fe897d47e2b712cf51\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qm5dhs1u\\pyaud
io_0fa5615a0f1d45fe897d47e2b712cf51\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'im
port sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Loca
l\\Temp\\pip-install-qm5dhs1u\\pyaudio_0fa5615a0f1d45fe897d47e2b712cf51\\setup.py
'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qm5dhs1u\
\pyaudio_0fa5615a0f1d45fe897d47e2b712cf51\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.cl
ose();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mst52wx_\install-record.txt' --single-version-exte
rnally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python37\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: So what happened when you tried to do what the message said you should do: `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools` ?

Comment: @Matthias Wish that was an answer so I could up vote it! XD

Answer (score 1):

you need to follow these two steps in order to install pyaudio:-

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

I hope this resolves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, please install the build tools:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a program that solves this for you. I will put the code in here. It uses the `os.system` function to do the CMD stuff for you, just an easier way to download it.

```
import os
os.system('cmd /k "pip install pipwin"')
os.system('cmd /k "pipwin install PyAudio"')
```

Then run that and it will do it all for you, if it doesn't work on the first try, just run it again. Sometimes it has to restart CMD for `pipwin` to start working